# Asynchronous Cocoa - Preventing "simple" (obvious) deadlocks in NSOperation?

Tags: objective-c, deadlock, nsoperation

When subclassing NSOperation to get a little chunk of work done, I've found out it's pretty easy to deadlock. Below I have a toy example that's pretty easy to understand why it never completes.

I can only seem to think through solutions that prevent the deadlock from the caller perspective, never the callee. For example, the caller could continue to run the run loop, not wait for finish, etc. If the main thread needs to be message synchronously during the operation, I'm wondering if there is a canonical solution that an operation subclasser can implement to prevent this type of deadlocking. I'm only just starting to dip my toe in async programming...

```
@interface ToyOperation : NSOperation

@end

@implementation ToyOperation

- (void)main
{
    // Lots of work

    NSString *string = @"Important Message";
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendMainThreadSensitiveMessage:) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:string waitUntilDone:YES];

    // Lots more work
}

- (void)sendMainThreadSensitiveMessage:(NSString *)string
{
    // Update the UI or something that requires the main thread...
}

@end

- (int)main
{
    ToyOperation *op = [[ToyOperation alloc] init];
    NSOperationQueue *opQ = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [opQ addOperations: @[ op ] waitUntilFinished:YES];    // Deadlock

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the main thread needs to be message synchronously during the
>   operation, I'm wondering if there is a canonical solution that an
>   operation subclasser can implement to prevent this type of
>   deadlocking.

There is.     *Never make a synchronous call to the main queue*.   And a follow-on:  *Never make a synchronous call from the main queue.*   And, really, it can be summed up as *Never make a synchronous call from any queue to any other queue.*

By doing that, you guarantee that the main queue is not blocked.   Sure, there may be an exceptional case that tempts you to violate this rule and, even, cases where it really, truly, is unavoidable.   But that very much should be the exception because even a single dispatch_sync() (or NSOpQueue waitUntilDone) has the potential to deadlock.

Of course, data updates from queue to queue can be tricky.   There are several options;   a concurrency safe data layer (very hard), only passing immutable objects or copies of the data (typically to the main queue for display purposes -- fairly easy, but potentially expensive), or you can go down the UUID based faulting like model that Core Data uses.   Regardless of how you solve this, the problem isn't anything new compared to any other concurrency model.

The one exception is when replacing locks with queues (For example, instead of using @synchronized() internally to a class, use a serial GCD queue and use dispatch_sync() to that queue anywhere that a synchronized operation must take place.   Faster and straightforward.).   But this isn't so much an exception as solving a completely different problem.